# How to delete only class files with eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I have dynamic web project in eclipse. I set my default output folders (my class files) to be in WebContent/WEB-INF/classes. I have another files in this folder like .properties and .xml files. The problem is when eclipse make clean or new compile or I dont know exactly but sometimes it delete all the files from this directory. Do u know how to set eclipse to delete only the class files and never touch the other ones?

Answer (score 0):

put your .properties , .xml files in source folder of your web project and not in classes folder. doing this way, eclipse will directly copy those files from source folder to classes folder after a build.

Comment: do you manually put those files (.properties etc) in WebContent/WEB-INF/classes? second question, do you have those files in src folder of your web project?

Comment: I have the filse in my src folder, yes. But they still do not copy into WebContent/WEB-INF/classes.

Comment: still I think there is a problem with your classpath. can you post your .classpath file content of your web project and project folder structure (i.e project filesystem tree, i.e Navigator snapshot with every folder expanded)